# Unable to install CherryPy

Tags: python, cherrypy

I know this is a very dumb question, but I can't install CherryPy. In the documentation is written:

> To install, change to the directory where setup.py is located and type (python-2.3 or later needed):
>
> ```
> python setup.py install
> ```

Which is what I do, I type this in Python Shell and it gives me error `Invalid syntax`, but I don't think I have any syntax errors.

Comment: Install `pip` and just do `pip install cherrypy`.

Comment: Also, just showing us `Invalid syntax` isn't enough for anyone to debug your problem. Post the log, or at least the whole error and traceback.

Comment: You need to run that in command prompt not in python shell. Python shell is for running python code like `print('stuff')`

Answer (score 4):

You won't install programs in the Python shell.  Navigate to where you downloaded the source and run `python setup.py install`.

Alternatively, you can use pip:

```
pip install cherrypy
```

Answer (score 2):

The best installation for Cherrypy, Mako, Python with terminal in Ubuntu is:

```
sudo apt-get install subversion python-mako python-simplejson python-cherrypy3 graphviz
```

And after `sudo apt-get update` and after `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

"I type this in Python Shell"...

Don't type that in the Python shell.

```
>>> python setup.py install
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python setup.py install
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Type it at the commandline.

```
$ python setup.py install
```

Or if you're on Windows:

```
C:\>python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found out the steps to install via command prompt, please fer to the attachment below. For me "python setup.py install" does not work but it works find for "setup.py install" after I pointed it properly to the directory>

Hope my experiment helps:
[Step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0LlF.jpg)
[Step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFspL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing on Mac and say you are using python 3, you would want to use:

```
sudo python3.3 setup.py build
```

Then after build is finished.

```
sudo python3.3 setup.py install
```